# Anonymous class creation can not be evaluated. Java Design Eclipse

Tags: java, class, anonymous

When I want to open the Design tab in Eclipse, I get this error: 
Anonymous class creation can not be evaluated.

In general case it is impossible to evaluate creation of anonymous class. So, expression ...

```
new AbstractFormatterFactory() { 
    @Override public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) { 
        NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance(); 
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); 
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format); 
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); 
        formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
        return formatter;
    } 
}
```

... was not evaluated.

The problem is in this block:

```
final JFormattedTextField textField1 = new JFormattedTextField(new Float(10.01));

textField1.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

    @Override
    public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
        NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
        return formatter;
    }
});
```

How can I solve this anonymous class thing?

Answer (score 1):

What is this warning stopping you from doing other then viewing it in a Design tool?

If it is causing a concern it will be due to a random bug in the plugin.

To work out the likely cause, comment out the whole function, test it is okay not and add back the method a line at a time to see when breaks the plugin.

Comment: It starts when the Override begins, any ideas?

Comment: So you are saying that `textField1.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

    @Override
    public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
        return null;
    }
});` breaks.  What if you take out the @Override?

Comment: if I take out the Override, it still doesn't work, I tried to comment line by line but the issue starts there. I really don't know what to do. It works fine when I run it, but I can't edit it from the Design tool

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the design tool?

Comment: I suggest you ask the eclipse forums as this appears to be a bug in that plugin.